# Proof of an infinite set according to Dedekind‘s definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let us assume $A' \subset A$ and $f\colon A \to A'$ is bijective (so $A$ is an infinite set according to Dedekind‘s definition). Let us further assume $h: A \to B$ is bijective. I want to prove that $B$ is also an infinite set.

There is a proof that goes like this:

We assume further $g = h \circ f \circ h^{-1} \colon B \to A \to A' \to B$. Now because of $A' \subset A$, there is an element $z \in A\setminus A'$. So $h(z) \in B$ but $\newcommand{\rng}{\mathrm{rng}}h(z) \notin \rng(g)$ because its image is $A'$ and there is no $z$ and therefore no $h(z)$ in $\rng(g)$. So we get $\rng(g) \subset B$ and then we have to show that there is some bijective function $B \to  \rng(g)$.

But the function $g$ does not seem possible since $h$ is defined as $A \to B$ while in $g$ the function $h$ becomes $A'\to B$. Also in that case $h(z)$ would not refer to the same object necessarily which seems also to kill the proof.

Are my objections legit? Can you give the correct proof including why the function $B \to \rng(g)$ must be injective (because it surely is surjective)? I see where the idea goes but the technicalities are way over my head.

Comment: $h(z)$ is defined for all $z\in A$, so it is also defined for all $z\in A'$.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say "the function $B\to \text{rng}(g)$". $B,\text{rng}(g)$ are sets, and no function is mentioned in "$B\to \text{rng}(g)$".

Comment: You already know that 1. the compositions of injections is also an injection, and 2. the compositions of surjections is a surjection?

Comment: My first point is that g is not possible because g: h ° f ° h^-1 = B -> A -> A’ -> B but that contradicts that h: A -> B, doesnt it?

Comment: No. Why do you think it's a contradiction?

Comment: Because h is defined to map from A to B but in g all of a sudden h maps from A‘ to B. That confuses me.

Comment: Every point in $A'$ is also in $A$. So if I take $z\in A'$, it's also in $A$, and $h(z)$ is defined.

Comment: Take $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $h(x)=x$. Take $f:[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\to[-1,1]$ given by $f(x)=\sin(x)$. Now we define $g:[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(x)=h\circ f(x)=\sin(x)$. Is this a contradiction?